# Error 414 when logging in with multiple accounts

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We're using GAE Python and allow users to login using their existing Google accounts. The login code is straightforward:

```
def _require_login(self, target_url="/"):
    if not self.user_bundle.user:
        return self.redirect(
            self.user_bundle.create_login_url(target_url),
            abort=True
        )
```

This creates a redirect to Google for the user to login, then upon successful login gets sent back to wherever they were originally trying to navigate.

The problem seems to be that if a user has more than a certain number of Google / GApps accounts logged in simultaneously (<strike>we're guessing 3 or more</strike> I can successfully reproduce it once I hit 5 accounts), they get an "Error 414" from Google:

[image: Google Error 414]

My brief search on the error states that the URL is too long, since it's a GET request. Just about all of the advice states to use POST instead. The problem is, we're using Google's built-in `create_login_url` method, which, as far as I can tell, doesn't provide a way to specify POST instead of GET.

How can we fix this?

Comment: Google multi-login simply. does. not. work. Never has, never will. Tell your users to use separate Chrome profiles for each login.

Comment: That's a pretty crappy answer. The Google Group for GAE leads to SO. I'm hoping for something more than that. We can't just tell users to change their browsing habits for our little webapp.

Comment: I haven't found a way to deal with this either, so I'm tagging in in hopes of finding an answer.

Comment: Question answered here: https://twitter.com/googlecloud/status/467411184430239745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Google Cloud Platform's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/googlecloud/status/467411184430239745):

> Unfortunately, only current fix is to logout of some accounts. >4 accounts logged in makes the URL too long (> 2048 bytes).

So now we're going to either make a pre-login page where it tells the user to log out of enough user accounts to meet the maximum number, or find an external library that allows us to let users log in without having to work around the limit.